# Why Switch case not working in normal class?

Tags: java

I have created a Project called Calculator in Netbeans and I have created 3 classes following Calculator, Operand, Calculation. I need to use switch-case statement in Calculation class but it show an error.

```
public class Calculation {  
Operand op = new Operand();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String opr = input.nextLine();

switch (txt) {
    case "+":
        System.Out.println(add());
        break;       
    case "-":
        substract();
        break;
    case "*":
        multiply();
        break;
    case "/":
        division();

        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
}

public double add(double total){
    total = op.getNo1()+op.getNo2();
    return total;
}

public double subtract(double total){
    total = op.getNo1()-op.getNo2();
    return total;
}

public double multiply(double total){
    total = op.getNo1() * op.getNo2();
    return total;
}

public double division(double total){
    total = op.getNo1()/op.getNo2();
    return total;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Switch must be in a method

Comment: So, this is basically just a "typo". Thus: please consider deleting this question. And for the next time, please read [mcve]. "I got an error" isn't regarded a valid problem description around here.

Answer (score 1):

`switch` must be inside the `main` method or inside any other method that you have defined. You can't write it outside a method like that.